# Objects in Java, how to compare parameters?

Tags: java, object, collections

Could anyone help me? I have a problem, I have some collections with costumers, sellers and products. I've made a GUI in which I can enter seller, costumer and products data for example: name, addres, ID and other stuff. Then we can construct sales with all the previous data.

The problem is the following, I want to make a kind of report (maybe just printing the sales) in which I can see the number of sales that every seller did.

Ive been trying with this code:

```
Object name = jcbSeller.getSelectedItem();
    String nameSeller = (String) name;
    System.out.println(nameSeller);

    Sale selectedSale = null;
    Seller selectedSeller = null;
    for(Sale sale : Collection.getSales())
    {
        selectedSale = sale;
        for(Seller seller : Collection.getSellers())
        {
            selectedSeller = seller;
            String name2 = selectedSeller.getName();
            if(nameSeller.equals(name2))
            {
                jtxaSale.setText(selectedSale.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("There is an error");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am putting the names of every seller and showing them in a JComboBox, then I go over the collections checking if there are sales. Then I compare the name of the JComboBox with the name of my seller that is contained in the sellers's collection. Finally I print the sale in console. But It just prints the first sale Ive done and if I change the seller, it prints the same sale.

I don't know if I explain the problem, I am new in this area. Hope you can help me. If you want more code Im going to put it. Thanks

Comment: People may well be able to help you. If you want help, change your post title from a sentence about needing help to a very brief description of your problem. Also, it'll help people if you translate the code into English.

Comment: Sorry, thank u so much.

Comment: Don't apologize, just [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: Are there any errors printing such as your "Hay un error"?

Comment: @Orin2005 Yes, it just prints the first sale Ive done and if I change the seller, the else statement print "There is an error".

Comment: @LuisH. instead of printing "There is an error", print something more descriptive such as `System.out.println(nameSeller + " is not equal to " + name2);` Then you will know the values that you are comparing and why they are not equal to eachother.

Comment: @Orin2005 First of all It says "Jhon is not equal to Alex" and If I change the seller it says "Alex is not equal to Jhon". It changes the names between them

Comment: @LuisH. This is probably because you are going through all `Seller`s in your `Collection.getSellers()`. So when you get one that is equal, you should `break` out of the loop, otherwise it will go through all the `Seller`s in the Collection.

Comment: @Orin2005 I tried that, in the first iteration it works good, but If I change the Seller it prints "Second seller is not equal to first seller" and if change to the first seller it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is due to looping through each Sale for each Seller, without having a reference between the two. You end up overriding the value you set over and over for each sale

```
...
if(nameSeller.equals(name2))
{
    jtxaSale.setText(selectedSale.toString());
    System.out.println("Adding selectedSale ("+ selectedSale.toString() + ") for selectedSeller ("+selectedSeller.toString()+")");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("There is an error");
}
```

Try this and see if the printing is as you intend.